# jQuery Click Table Row Toggle Section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablerow

I have the following markup (which I have no control and must remain as is, however the JavaScript can be manipulated.)

http://jsbin.com/uyifu3/edit

What I'm trying to accomplish is that when the table row is clicked the the "Toggle Me Here" link is automatically clicked.

I keep finding my self getting into a recursive loop with the current setup.

So clicking anywhere in the table row (minus actually clicking on the link itself) should click the link which there for will toggle the red box.  click on the link independent of the table row should toggle the red box as normal without calling the 'selectedRow' click event being fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer, the below answer *isn't an optimal solution*.  Go with [@karim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70393/karim79)'s solution using  unobtrusive handlers if at all possible.

If his solution is *not* an option, e.g. this link is auto-generated by something, then you can do this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.selectedRow').click(function(e) {
    if(e.target.nodeName != 'A')
      $(this).find('td:last a').click();
  });
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/FGXcD/), it just checks that the click didn't originate from the anchor in the first place.  If that's the case, it's done what it need to do, the `click` event bubbling up to the row should take no action.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening (I think) is that when you click on the anchor, the event bubbles up and triggers the one bound to the row. I would suggest binding to the anchor as follows:

```
  $('.toggleMe').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation(); // prevent event from bubbling up the DOM tree
      $("#box").toggle();        
  });
```

Also, remove the inline function call from the anchor, and give it the class `.toggleMe` or such (used in the above click handler):

```
<a class="toggleMe" href="#">Toggle Me Here</a>
```

Try it here: http://jsbin.com/uyifu3/7/edit (clicking on the anchor will *not* trigger the `.selectedRow` click event, to which I added an alert).

Comment: Yes, definitely stop the event from bubbling up in the toggleMe code.  Since aherrick said the html can not be changed, just stop the event propagation in the toggleMe function that is called via the inline onclick.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    $('#box').toggle();
});
```

and just remove any functionality for `toggleMe()` so that essentially clicking the link is no different than clicking the row. it's just there for show :)

Answer (score 0):

Try backing out to a common parent (the row/tr in this example) and then drill back down to the target (a with an onclick handler).

```
$(e.target).parents('tr').first().find('td:last a').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there's more than one row (since you're using a class for the `TR`). This code would work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Remove the anchors
  $(".selectedRow td:last a").each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
  });

  // Make entire row clickable
  $(".selectedRow").click(function(e){
    $('#box').toggle();
  });
});
```

Essentially it removes the `toggleMe()` anchors and makes the entire row clickable.

Here's the [code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/nwTvb/).